# Is it possible to constrain a generic type parameter to String OR Array

Tags: c#, string, generics

In short: is it possible to define a generic method where the type parameter (`T`) is constrained to `string` or `int[]`? In pseudo-C#, what I want to do is:

```
public static int MyMethod<T> ( T arg1, T arg2 ) 
    where T : (has an indexer that returns an int) {
    // stuff with arg1[i], arg2[j], etc...
}
```

Note that in C#, due to the built-in `string` indexer (which returns a `char`) along with implicit conversion from   `char` to `int`, the following expression means precisely the same thing whether `source` is a `string` or an `int[]`:

```
int someval = source[index];
```

Per the thread [Constrain generic extension method to base types and string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831177/constrain-generic-extension-method-to-base-types-and-string) I realize I can't just make a list of unassociated types in the `where T : x...` constraint clause. Both `int[]` and `string` would comply with `T: IEnumerable<int>`, but `IEnumerable<T>` does not require implementers to have an indexer, which is exactly the common feature I am using from both types.

The purpose behind this is that I'm building some highly optimized string parsing and analyzing functions such as a fast implementation of the Damerau–Levenshtein distance algorithm. I've found that first converting my strings to arrays of int can sometimes yield significantly faster executions in repetitive character-by-character processing (as with the D-L algorithm). This is largely due to the fact that comparing `int` values is much faster that comparing `char` values.

The operative word is 'sometimes'. Sometimes it's faster to operate directly on the strings and avoid the cost of first converting and copying to arrays of `int`. So I now have methods that are truly identical except for the declarations.

Of course I can use `dynamic`, but the performance penalty from runtime checking completely destroys any gains made in the construction of the methods. (I **did** test it).

Comment: In what sense is it sensical to treat `T` statically as *either* one type or another?  The point of constraints is to allow you operate on variables of type `T` and expect a minimum level of type compatibility.  Constraining to two mutually incompatible types is bizzarre.

Comment: @kirk-woll : As I describe in detail, they are not mutually incompatible for my purposes. On the contrary, they are identical. I have built and am using methods that are 100% identical, except that the parameters in one version are declared as `string` and in the other version are declared as `int[]`. In both cases I am operating on each member of the collection as an integer.

Comment: No. A `string` and (any) `Array` unify at `object`, A string is *not* a `char[]` in C#, although you can create a `char[]` *from* a string, but that's a *new* array object with the contents copied over.

Comment: @pst : The string indexer, also aliased as the Chars property, (see [String.Chars Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars.aspx)) offers direct index access to a character, without copying. It is separate from ToCharArray(), which does copy the contents to a new object.

Comment: @jmh_gr Types are still nominative in C#, not structural.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have a constraint that says “the type must have an indexer”.

However, you can have a constraint that says “the type must implement an interface that has an indexer”. Such an interface might be `IList<char>`, for example.

Unfortunately, `string` doesn’t implement `IList<char>`, so you would have to write a small wrapper class for it:

```
sealed class StringWrapper : IList<char>
{
    public string String { get; private set; }
    public StringWrapper(string str) { String = str; }
    public static implicit operator StringWrapper(string str)
    {
        return new StringWrapper(str);
    }

    public char this[int index]
    {
        get { return String[index]; }
        set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }

    // Etc.... need to implement all the IList<char> methods
    // (just throw NotSupportedException except in the ones that are trivial)
}
```

And then you can declare your method like this:

```
public static TElement MyMethod<TCollection, TElement>(TCollection arg)
    where TCollection : IList<TElement>
{
    return arg[0];
}

[...]

MyMethod<StringWrapper, char>("abc")     // returns 'a'
MyMethod<int[], int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3 })  // returns 1
```

Comment: This did in fact work. A very clever use of the `implicit operator` statement. I modified the `StringWrapper` example to implement `IList<int>`, constrained my methods to `T: IList<int>`, and calling the methods with both `string` and `int[]` arguments compiled successfully. Unfortunately it was still very slow, so I won't actually be using it. (Both `dynamic` and the presented `IList` wrapper versions were 2.8x slower than separate explicit `int[]` and `string` overloads).

Comment: I am very surprised that you say it is as slow as `dynamic`, but you seem to have tested it, so I believe you. I hope this means that dynamic is surprisingly fast, and not that interface method dispatch is surprisingly slow.

Comment: I did some different tests today on a larger set of more hetergenous data, and my results came back very different: the generic <int> was only 5% slower than an explicit `int[]` overload; generic <StringWrapper> was only 15% slower than an explicit `string` overload; while `dynamic` was about 50% slower than the explicit overloads.

Answer (score 5):

No, C# does not allow you to create a "composite" constraint like that.

The expression you show does mean the same thing, but you can't use that fact to your advantage. C# generics resemble C++ templates syntactically, but they work completely differently, so the fact that the indexer does the same thing ends up being irrelevant.

You could, of course, just create the two overloads with the specific types you need, but that does mean some annoying copy & paste. Any attempts at abstracting this to avoid repetition will cost you performance badly.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your method signature

```
public static int MyMethod<T> ( T[] arg1, T[] arg2 )
```

and use String.ToCharArray() before passing string arguments (or maybe in an overload, you get the idea...)

Comment: The only issue with this is that the OP is "building some highly optimized string parsing and analyzing functions" - this would not be very fast at all.

Comment: Alas, that defeats the purpose of using the string indexer -- index access _without_ copying the contents. If I'm going to convert to an array I'll just convert to an array of `int`, easily done with an extension method.